# Study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\pi)(\log(n^2+n)-\log(n^2))$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think I've found the solution, but I want to make sure it's correct. First of all

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\pi)(\log(n^2+n)-\log(n^2))
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \log({n^2+n\over n^2}) 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \log(1+{1\over n})$

Then I use the fact that $log(1+{1\over n})\sim _{n\to \infty} \frac1n$ so the initial series behaves like the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac1n$, which is the alternating harmonic series, and, since it converges, so does the other.

Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Why "since it converges then it [our series] converges"? You could use Leibniz Test for alternating series, instead.

Comment: Because the two series are asymptotically equivalent so, by comparison, they both converge.

Comment: Your title implies that you're trying to _evaluate_ this series, but your question text appears only concerned with the _convergence_ of the series. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: My bad, I edited the title.

Comment: "Because the two series are asymptotically equivalent so, by comparison, they both converge." No, classical counterexample: $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^nn^{-1/2}\quad\text{vs.}\quad\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^n(n^{-1/2}+(-1)^nn^{-1}).$$

Comment: @colis, sorry: what does "asymptotically equivalent" means in this context? And how do you use the comparison text as this is for positive series and the on in your question is not one of those?

Comment: @Timbuc you're right... I can't use that test. But, since $\log(1+{1\over n})$ is monotonic decreasing as $n\to\infty$, and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \log(1+{1\over n})=0$, by Leibniz test the series converges. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Indeed so, @colis. That's what I wrote in my first comment.

Comment: You can use the [Wallis formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisFormula.html) to find the value of the series.